# Deciding between Umbraco and Orchard ASP.NET CMS

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, e-commerce, umbraco, orchardcms

Now that both system's are built on ASP.NET MVC, does anyone have any experience dealing with both? Looking to set up a small business site for a friend, that will eventually have an online store. I've read a lot of posts, but nothing recent ( since Umbraco 5 was released ). If you've had experience, just looking for pros and cons. Anything related to commerce functionality would be helpful as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Orchard has been built from ground-up around ASP.NET MVC 3. I personally prefer that one, as it's well designed, very active and backed by Microsoft. And, of course, totally free.

If you are looking for e-commerce solution - there is a new, very promising module called WebShop, along with a [full tutorial](http://skywalkersoftwaredevelopment.net/blog/writing-an-orchard-webshop-module-from-scratch-part-1).

Comment: I totally forgot about that tutorial, indeed

Comment: link is broken, is this the one we're looking for?
http://www.ideliverable.com/blog/writing-an-orchard-webshop-module-from-scratch-part-1

Comment: I guess so, yes. I'll let Sipke know his old links are down - thanks for finding this out.

Answer (score 6):

Orchard is very dynamic and u can build your site out of parts, a e-commerce module would be able to provide parts that can be rendered as partial views. Another custom module could inject other views in there. It's just very extensible and i like it. U can allow some access to the admin panel just for store administrators etc.

I don't know about Umbraco with ASP.NET MVC as base, but i know Orchard is from Outercurve Foundation which i like alot.

As far as i know there is just one real commerce module, but i don't know if it is any good

[Orchard gallery - Mageliawebstore](http://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/ByCategory/Modules/Commerce)

[Mageliawebstore directly](http://mageliawebstore.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Another link http://www.magelia.org/

Answer (score 3):

Hi Don't know about Orchard but Umbraco V5 is ideal for a small business. The reason that you don't read a lot of post recently is that the Architecture is completely new. Expect a lot of documentation in the coming month. But you can already start with the site you get a lot of info if you are using the create template dialog in the backend which renders some default code for you.

Regarding Ecommerce I know the Package vendors of [UWebshop](http://www.uwebshop.com/) and [UCommerce](http://www.ucommerce.dk/) are already building next versions of their products on top of Umbraco V5 so expect a fully integrated Ecommerce solution soon.

Comment: Umbraco v5 has been cancelled since.

Comment: http://umbraco.com/follow-us/blog-archive/2012/6/13/v5-rip.aspx

Comment: Version 6 is a bit of a mess

Comment: Version 7 just a re-skin

Answer (score 1):

This is a time-relative answer, but if you want an MVC based .NET CMS then your only real choice between the two is Orchard at this time. [Umbraco 5 saw an early retirement](http://umbraco.com/follow-us/blog-archive/2012/6/13/v5-rip.aspx) so it's back to webforms, although as of 4.10 MVC support was bolted on and I believe there are some modules out there that give 4.x some MVC support as well. Orchard, on the other hand, is built on ASP.NET MVC 3 from the ground up and [incorporates a handful of other cool technologies](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/How-Orchard-works#OrchardFoundations) that make writing clean code that adheres to industry standard best practices easier.